# < and > are not allowed on http request?

Tags: jquery, post

i have a web application in MVC which can share files which get stored in some sharePoint location and the link is shown in our appication. It is implemented as follows.

we are using form tag for the same.

```
 <form id ="addformupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> some html tags     here for implementing the form here </form> as below.
```

[image]

we are using JQuery `POST` for the same.

```
    var options = {
        url: "../../DataService/SaveResources",
        success: layoutService.SPfileUploadResponse
    };
```

i.e user can give a "`File Description`", and he has to browse the file which is to be uploaded.
It works absolutely fine, but when he give the file name as `<test>`, it fails.
Pleae let me know the solution (if any)?

Comment: basically along the httprequest, < xyz > are not transferred as it is potentially unsafe.

Comment: @ismailbaig: Thanks for the reply.is there any alternative to some how achieve the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Net pipeline (I'm assuming that's whats in use here, with the mention of MVC and Sharepoint), disallows some characters that can be dangerous (such as the < and > characters, as those could be used for XSS).

Normally, this is a good thing to leave on. However, if you are absolutely sure you're handing character escaping correctly (If you use the @Model.Value syntax in Razor, or <%: syntax pre-razor, this is done for you), you can apply the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to your action method, and it will then allow these unsafe characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. i will check and let you update on this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is potentially unsafe to put the posts with "<" and ">". It is better to avoid it.